# How to get all checkboxes in to one object array and mark checked ones

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have his code which is selecting all checked checkboxes:

```
var checkedCbs = document.querySelectorAll('#priceTree input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
var ids = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkedCbs.length; i++) ids.push(checkedCbs[i].id);
```

But I want my object array contained all checkboxes but the ones which is checked just mark then as checked flag

```
chbs = [{ 'id': 'id1', 'checked': false },{ 'id': 'id2', 'checked': true}]
```

How can I achieve that in vanila js?

Answer (score 3):

Read `checked(Boolean)` property of the element and you should not have `:checked` in `querySelectorAll` as that would select only `checked` elements.

```js
var checkedCbs = document.querySelectorAll('#priceTree input[type="checkbox"]');
var ids = [];
for (var i = 0; i < checkedCbs.length; i++) {
  ids.push({
    id: checkedCbs[i].id,
    checked: checkedCbs[i].checked
  });
}
```

Comment: Great, but I think *map* would come in handy here… ;-)

Comment: @RobG, _Deleted posts can not be upvoted..Unfortunately_ ;(

Answer (score 1):

use [].map.call

```
var checkedCbs = document.querySelectorAll('#priceinput[type="checkbox"]:checked');
[].map.call(checkedCbs, function(a){
  return { 
     id: a.id, 
     checked': a.checked 
  }
});
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

```
//select all checkbox
var sele = document.querySelectorAll('#priceTree input[type="checkbox"]');
var i = 0;
var chbs = [];
for (i=0; i<sele.length; i++) {
    //push id checked status and id
    chbs.push({'checked' : sele[i].checked, 'id':sele[i].id});
}
```